# Parse list type data into different format to make compatible for spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-data-grid, datasheet

I am new in JavaScript and react If can't explain the problem correctly, please post a comment so at least I can tell more.

Thanks a million in advance will appreciate if anyone can give me a little help

I've been stumped on this for hours and hours  I can't figure out a solution to solve this problem.

Say I have data in list type which need to parse from one format to another formate So that I can make compatible with the react-datasheet format to display the spreadsheet

```
Sample data:

const sampleData = [
  {
    question: "what is your name?",
    answer: "Ben",
    topic: "names"
  },
  {
    question: "what is your name?",
    answer: "Will",
    topic: "names"
  },
  {
    question: "What is your brother's age?",
    answer: 55,
    topic: "ages"
  }
]
```

```
Expected results 
 grid: [
        [
          { readOnly: true, value: "SL" },
          { value: "topic", readOnly: true },
          { value: "question", readOnly: true },
          { value: "answer", readOnly: true },
        ],
        [
          { readOnly: true, value: 1 },
          { value: 'names' },
          { value: ' what is your name?' },
          { value: 'Ben' },
        ],
        [
          { readOnly: true, value: 2 },
          { value:'names' },
          { value: 'what is your name?' },
          { value: 'Willi' },
        ],
        [
          { readOnly: true, value: 3 },
          { value: 'ages' },
          { value: "What is your brother's age?" },
          { value: 33 },
        ],
      ]
```

Comment: What is the relation between the input and output?

Comment: if anyone can help me a little bit please will appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const sampleData = [
  {
    question: "what is your name?",
    answer: "Ben",
    topic: "names"
  },
  {
    question: "what is your name?",
    answer: "Will",
    topic: "names"
  },
  {
    question: "What is your brother's age?",
    answer: 55,
    topic: "ages"
  }
]

// First, for each object in sampleData, construct an array of objects:
var grid = sampleData.map(function(currentValue, index, a) {
    return [
        { readOnly: true, value: index + 1 },
        { value: currentValue.topic },
        { value: currentValue.question },
        { value: currentValue.answer }
    ];
});

// Then prepend the "header/config" array of objects:
grid.unshift([
    { readOnly: true, value: "SL" },
    { value: "topic", readOnly: true },
    { value: "question", readOnly: true },
    { value: "answer", readOnly: true },
]);

// Finally, wrap grid in an object:
var expectedResults = {
    grid: grid
}
console.log(expectedResults);
```

Comment: Thanks a million, #Leftium